# android - What's the unit of battery current value?

Tags: android, battery, batterymanager

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399709/is-there-any-way-to-get-instant-power-consumption-for-android?noredirect=1#comment62336746_37399709), what's the unit found on the /sys Battery Current file? The values I get are usually between 300000 and 800000.

I'm currently using a Motorola Moto G 2nd Generation (XT1068) and the Battery Current file is on `/sys/class/power_supply/bms/current_now`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to someone on a [Google Groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/bFLWckViUjk), it is **microamps** (μA).

Comment: As a simple check, most batters are 3.7VDC. So the wattage range is 1.1 to 3 Watts, which is very reasonable. If the current had been *10 smaller or larger (.3W and 30W), the values wouldn't have made much sense.